# How to know when focus changes in a CDialog derived class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

"Common Controls" send out a NM_SETFOCUS notification, but not basic controls like an edit control.

Is there a way in my CDialog-derived class to know when focus changes to ANY control in my dialog?  If not within my dialog, then possibly ANY focus change (I can figure it out from the hwnd)?

Comment: I know I can brute-force it (gotta remember to set the "Notify" style flag for the button controls), but there should be a better way without having to map different types of control notification messages to every single control.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle [CWnd::OnCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t3ddsb9.aspx) and trap the command ID and notification message.  I'd try something like this...

```
if((notificationCode == EN_KILLFOCUS)        ||   
            (notificationCode == LBN_KILLFOCUS) ||
            (notificationCode == CBN_KILLFOCUS) ||
            (notificationCode == NM_KILLFOCUS)  ||
            (notificationCode == WM_KILLFOCUS))

{

 // Here do whatever you want.

}
```

You can expand it by adding the equivalent _SETFOCUS notifications.

Comment: This will not work because notification codes are not globally unique across all controls.  LBN_SETFOCUS is 4 and CBN_SETFOCUS is 3, but LBN_SELCANCEL is 3 and CBN_KILLFOCUS is 4, hence you must pair a specific control type with a specific notification code.  I was hoping MFC had a general "OnGeneralSetFocus(int iControlID)".

Comment: Don't think so.  You'll need to couple it with a bit of logic.  Once you know the notification code and the focused control, you can do what you need to do.  The only other alternative would be to try to craft something with a hook.  But, I don't think that's worth the effort.

Comment: I can brute force it using the existing MFC mechanisms (see my comment to my question).  I just did not want to have to do it for EVERY control, which is similar to what you are recommending, yours is just at a lower level, and just as much a maintenance nightmare as doing it at the MFC level (e.g. I add a new CEdit control to the dialog resource...).  Doh!